# Quickbooks API + Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am creating a Jupyter Notebook (http://jupyter.org/) in order to pull financial data from our current accounting software (Quickbooks Online).

I've worked through Quickbook's API explorer, but cannot find any documentation related to authorization for Quickbooks API; each request that I submit via the Jupyter Notebook is an authentication error.

I was wondering if there is a simple command (e.g quickbooks.apikey = [API KEY]) that I can use to pass my API key and authenticate properly.

NOTE: I do not need this to be a production-server so I do not think OAuth is necessary - just need to pass along my API key so that I can pull down a Report locally.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> but cannot find any documentation related to authorization for Quickbooks API;

Here you go:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/00_quickbooks_online/2_build/10_authentication_and_authorization

> I was wondering if there is a simple command (e.g quickbooks.apikey = [API KEY]) that I can use to pass my API key and authenticate properly.

Authentication is via OAuth. You need to use OAuth.

> NOTE: I do not need this to be a production-server so I do not think OAuth is necessary

OAuth is necessary.